# Replace specific value within file

Tags: python, string, file

I'm trying to replace one value in a file with a values. Everything works fine but when I look at the file after its completed there no change at all. What can I use for this?

Content of the file:

```
22102014,1646,1,0,1848,3559,5,0,1848,0,0,1,0,1,1664,4997,2257,9,0,1664
```

I just want to change the tird value from `1` to `0`.

Here is the code as I have it:

```
# Read in the file
with open("datafile", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

# Replace the target string
data.replace('1', '0')

# Write the file out again
with open("datafile", 'w') as f:
    f.write (data)
```

CanIi do this with `str.replace`?

Comment: You need to assign the result, `data = data.replace(...)`; strings are *immutable*. But do you want to replace **all** zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in your question that you want to replace the **third** value with a `0`.  If so, then `str.replace` is not what you want to use because it will replace **every** `1` with a `0`.

Instead, you can use the following:

```
# Read in the file
with open("datafile", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

lst = data.split(',')   # Split data on , with str.split
lst[2] = '0'            # Replace the value at index 2 (the third value)
data = ','.join(lst)    # Rebuild the string with str.join

# Write the file out again
with open("datafile", 'w') as f:
     f.write(data)
```

The string methods `str.split` and `str.join` are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq).